# All SQL Server aliases linked to default instance instead of instance I assigned

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, sql-server-2017

I have multiple SQL Server instances(different versions) on my computer.
I try to create aliases for each instance as 
[image]

First I thought I had everything settled then I found no matter which alias name I connect, it will all be led to SQL2017 instance.

I wanna provide more information but don't know where to start with.
And idea what I might do wrong?

Comment: Different instances must have different `Port no`, using a default port (1433) you of course connect to the default instance

Comment: @DenisRubashkin I thought that's something SQL Server browser will take care for me, lesson learned!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To correctly connect to SQL Server instance the `network library` has to know 2 things: `IP address` and `port number`. These two are necessary and sufficient.

The "name" of a `named instance` make no difference to the `library`, it was invented when `named instances` were introduced and it is used just to determine the `port number`.

When the `port number` is missing in the `connection string`, the `network library` asks for it `SQL Server Browser` (on UDP 1434) sending it the `instance name`. As the responce it receives `port number`.

When there is `port number` in the connection string, **instance name is just ignored**.

You can test it by yourself by changing `instance name` to `bla-bla-bla`:
if you create an `alias` or just type in `SSMS` connection dialog `.\bla-bla-bla,1433`
you'll be connected to the `default instance`.

Vice versa, if you omit `instance name` of the `named instance` but indicate the correct `port` where your  `named instance` is listening on, for example `.,8852` where `8852` is the `port` of `named instance` you'll be connected to this `named instance` even if it's name was not specified.

Answer (score 1):

The port number is very essential when you have named instances running on a box. For each alias to be unique, you will need to use the port number associated with each instance which can found in the tcp/ip properties.

1. Note down the Static port number for each instance.
2. Specify the port number while creating alias

A few useful links :

1. [MSDN Link](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dbrowne/2012/05/21/how-to-add-a-hostname-alias-for-a-sql-server-instance/)
2. [Sample blog](https://mariusschulz.com/blog/how-to-configure-a-sql-server-alias-for-a-named-instance-on-a-development-machine)

The parameter field and Server are most important which direct the traffic to the correct instance.

For example , the below will connect to the hostname(Provide the server name here) and to the instance which is listening on 2466.

[image]

To connect remotely from App server (any other), you will need to configure same alias name using **cliconfg.exe** for both 64 and 32 bit. This will help you connect to the alias remotely.

Answer (score 1):

You also will need to make sure that the other instances are NOT using dynamic ports - otherwise your port number may change after a restart and your Alias will again be broken.